# How can I check if many strings are not empty in Erlang?

Tags: string, erlang, conditional-statements

I have `S1`, `S2` and `S3`, I want to make something like:

`if S1 != "" and S2 != "" and S3 != "" then do something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that strings in Erlang are just integer lists, you can do the following:

```
case S1 =/= [] andalso S2 =/= [] andalso S3 =/= [] of
  true -> do_something;
  false -> do_something_else
end
```

Using `""` instead of `[]` would work as well.

Answer (score 7):

If all must be empty for you to perform some action,

```
case {S1,S2,S3} of
    {[],[],[]} -> %% empty
    _ -> %% not empty
end.
```

If you need to know which one is empty

```
case {S1,S2,S3} of
    {[],[],[]} -> %% empty
    {[],_,_} -> %% S1 empty
    {_,[],_} -> %% S2 empty
    {_,_,[]} -> %% S3 empty
end.
```

Cleaner code !!

---

**EDIT**

```
case lists:member(true,[Each =:= []  || Each <- [S1,S2,S3]]) of
    true -> 
        %% atleast one of them is empty
    false -> 
        %% all are not empty
end.
```

Comment: You missed the cases for two empty strings (in which case only the first of them is detected with this code). Pattern matching is always the way to go, though. +1

Comment: I need to do something when all are not empty.

Comment: This sort of thing is why lists:all/2 exists.

Comment: @RichardC: Yes, like `lists:all([L == [] || L <- [S1, S2, S3]])`.